# Does Vue's ref perform a DOM lookup each time it is used?

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js

I am currently testing Vue.js, and using a few *refs* in my project.
I am not sure if every time I call a ref in my method, a DOM Lookup is performed, or if vue stores all refs once and then accesses the reference.

I couldn't find an answer on the documentation nor via google.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Example

```
myDiv = this.$refs.myDiv
```

Do I need to store the ref in a variable myself or is there no performance impact when calling the ref multiple times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going through the source code, when a vue instance is initiated it sets the property `$ref = { }` to an empty object. See [`initLifecycle` function](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/instance/lifecycle.js#L40)

This `vm.$refs` object is populated by checking if the virtual node has `ref` attribute i.e `vnode.data.ref` in the [`registerRef`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/modules/ref.js#L20) function.

So you do not have to do this yourself.

And referencing `$refs.myRef` does not perform a DOM lookup. It will be managed by virtual dom patch process.

Answer (score 4):

`does ref perform a DOM lookup each time?`

The short answer is **No**.

Here's my rough understanding: (Please correct me if I am wrong)

Vue uses virtual DOM. In Vue, a virtual representation of a real DOM is VNode. Vue creates a VNode first based on the templates and scripts. After that, Vue compares the virtual DOM (the tree containing all the VNodes) with the real DOM. If there are differences between real and virtual DOM, **Vue create the DOM element using `document.createElement` (or other DOM creating function). `document.createElement` returns the pointer to the actual DOM element. The pointer is saved into `Vnode.elm` before the element is appended to the display.** Whenever a Vnode is created/updated/destroyed, Vue checks the ref attribute and set `this.$refs.refname` as `Vnode.elm`.

In other words, **there's never a DOM lookup**. Vnode already contains the pointer to the real DOM element. When you use ref, Vue will just assign the existing DOM pointer to the `$refs`

Answer (score 0):

The references are registered once and cached in the `$refs` object. You can use them directly, no problem.